# Making Sections Absolute / Not-Relocatable in a Linker Script

Tags: linker, linker-scripts

I am trying to write a linker script such that certain sections will be relocatable and other sections will be not. I am aware of the `-r` flag, which makes all sections relocatable. However, for a certain section I require absolute symbols.

My linker script so far looks like:

```
MEMORY {
        rom     : ORIGIN = 0x09000000, LENGTH = 32M
        ewram   : ORIGIN = 0x02000000, LENGTH = 4M - 4k
}

SECTIONS {
        .text : 
        ALIGN(4)
        {
                *(.text*)
        }

        .rodata :
        ALIGN(4)
        {
                *(.rodata*)
        } >rom = 0xff
        . = 0x2003000;
        not_relocatable :
        ALIGN(4)
        {
                *(not_relocatable*)
        }
        /* Discard everything not specifically mentioned above. */
        /DISCARD/ :
        {
                *(*);
        }
}
```

When linking with `ld ... -r -o linked.o`, all symbols in my input files in `not_relocatable*` will not be located at 0x2003000. For a single symbol, I know what I want to achieve is possible using the `ABSOLUTE` expression, e.g.

```
. = 0x2003000;
        not_relocatable :
        ALIGN(4)
        {
                my_absolute_symbol = ABSOLUTE(.);
        }
```

However, I want to place all symbols that match `*(not_relocatable*)` at an absolute address without explicitly listing out all such symbols.

What is the correct way to achieve this?